# Remote connect to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't use php or mysql but I am trying to upgrade a phpbb board I got but the one click installer forgot to install some stuff in the database so I can't upgrade to the newest version till I add the missing stuff.

So I need to do a remote connect to mysql database but I am not sure how to do this or what software I need(free, and very easy to setup I don't want to spend much time on this).

I don't really want to use phpmyadmin since I don't want to start setting up a virtual directory and whatever else it needs to be installed. Like I said I don't do php or mysql I just choose it since in my hosting package it was one click to install phpbb and I had a mysql database free.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the trial version of [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com) or [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to verify that your host allows external connections to the database. Once you've done that you can add a MySQL user that can connect from outside, then use something like [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) or [crunchyfrog](http://code.google.com/p/crunchyfrog/) to connect and operate.

Comment: FYI, MySQL Administrator has been merged with MySQL Query Browser in the MySQL Workbench....finally!

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Workbench Download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

GUI tool that should do everything you need.

Previous link was for the download, here is the product page for more info:

[MySQL Workbench Documentation](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: Does it not have a 64bit version?

Comment: Looks like the latest version does have 64bit support, although I have not used it on a 64bit OS yet.

http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding connectively to mysql here are some things to look out for that sometimes may inhibit you from connecting remotely.  Depending on how you installed it you may not be able to connect remotely at all...

bind_address set to 127.0.0.1
skip_networking option set to true

With either of these configurations above you'll only be able to connect from the local machine.

In order to verify that mysql is actually listening for remote connections you can try:

telnet host 3306

If it connects then you can connect and you can probably figure out the rest from there.